# SQLCMD -g option

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

We have a new client who will give us a a weekly extraction of data from his SQL server so that we can perform our services on the data.  The director of IT is very much security minded and wants the data to be encrypted.  We have said that he can encrypt his file using PGP and we can exchange public keys.  However, he has asked us if "we support the 'SQLCMD -g' option".  This makes no sense as this is his SQL server and it is HIS extract.  Therefore, he is the one executing the SQLCMD if that's what he wants.   But before going back to him, I wanted to cover all my bases as I am not familiar with the "-g" option.  I have search on the internet and there seems to be little information on how it's actually used.  I have read [MS sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15), [MS Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), and finally [Configure Always Encrypted using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15).  But I still don't understand how the "-g" is actually used when executing "SQLCMD".  Anyone who has a link or can provide a basic sqlcmd example using this option, it will go a long way to help me understand what he's really asking, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Agreed. It makes no sense. If an application connects into this SQL Server and issues `-g` it's still going to get plain-text back. The application in this case is `sqlcmd` which you are not running. His problem is to encrypt the plain-text file, which pgp is made for. It's an odd request for him to make unless he is wanting you to connect to the database directly.

Comment: JNevill. Thanks for the confirmation.  I will update this question if I learn anything from him.  But if anyone has an example usage, that will still help me.